# Find the date/time a process was created in OpenVMS

Tags: openvms

I can't seem to find the date/time a process was created in OpenVMS V8.3-1H1.

The `sh proc/all PROCESS_NAME` command does show a *Connect time* which at first I though it is the time since the process was created, but after a few tests I discovered that it is not.

I have search the PDF documents I have from HP, the *Ask the Wizard* archive and openvms.org but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *HP OpenVMS DCL Dictionary*, for `f$getjpi` explains the item code `LOGINTIM` as String, Process creation time. So try a

```
$ write sys$output f$getjpi(0,"LOGINTIM")
```

and see if that's what you want/need.